# Assistance needed for a syntax error with my simple PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm calling a db link with some PL/SQL and I'm having issues with commas and pipes. I've tried multiple combinations but keep getting syntax errors.

I've tried multiple commas all over the place, to no avail :-(

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000);
s_sql varchar2(4000);
l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';

begin

for c in (select * from my_table)
loop
if 
c.blue_table is not null 
then v_sql := 
'select count(*) from' ||c.schema||'.'||c.table||'@'||'l_dblink;
execute immediate v_sql into s_sql;
dbms_output.put_line(s_sql);
end if;
end loop;
end;
/
```

I'm expecting it to loop through the table 'my_table'. put together 'SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME' and give me a row count.

Comment: Some bell end has voted this down - why?

Comment: Not sure abt the downvote, but you seem to have an extra `'` after `'@'||`

Comment: Maybe somebody downvoted because you didn't explain what the error message is or nor what line it occurs.

Comment: You're also missing a space in your string concat. `from` and the schema name are stuck together.

Comment: Legend. Sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some minor syntax issues

```
declare
  v_sql    varchar2(4000);
  s_sql    pls_integer; -- better to use a numeric type variable for returning result of "count"
  l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
begin
  for c in (select * from my_table) loop
    if c.blue_table is not null then
      v_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || c.schema || '.' || c.table || '@' ||l_dblink;
                                  --^ "space needed"                         [^ quote is removed ]
      execute immediate v_sql into s_sql;
      dbms_output.put_line(s_sql);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed this around a bit and realised it still wasn't working, with help from these guys here I sorted it out. Thanks.

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000);
s_sql varchar2(4000);
l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';

begin


for c in (select * from my_table)
loop
if 
c.blue_table is not null 
then
execute immediate' select count(*) from '||c.schema||'.'||c.table|| '@' ||l_dblink into s_sql;
dbms_output.put_line(s_sql);
end if;
end loop;
end;
/
```